# MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:Column 'id' cannot be null

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, one-to-many

I'm using one to many relationship with hibernate and spring boot and I'm getting this error

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'invoice_id' cannot be null

My Entity classes

Invoice.java

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Invoice {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="invoice_id")
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "invoice")
    private List<Product> products;
}
```

Product.java

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column
    private int product_id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="invoice_id")
    private Invoice invoice;
}
```

For creating invoice I need to create products so when I try to save Product I'm getting error

ProductService.java

```
@Service
public class ProductService {

    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    public void saveProduct(Product product){
        product.setDate(new Date());
        product.setStatus("Active");
        productRepository.save(product);
    }
}
```

Am I using annotations correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Column(name="invoice_id")
```

Either rename it to

```
@Column(name="id")
```

or remove it.

Comment: glad i cold help :)

Answer (score 1):

Here Product Table has a foreign key reference from Invoice which is not null and you are saving Product without the Invoice reference, so you are getting com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'invoice_id' cannot be null

SO While saving Product you need to map invoice_id too .

I am providing the correct approach in the below code snippet

```
@Service
public class ProductService {

    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    @Autowired
    private InvoiceRepository invoiceRepository;

    public void saveInvoiceAndProduct(){
        //either get the existing Invoice Data from db or save new one
        Invoice invoice = new Invoice();
        List<Product> prods = new ArrayList<>();

        Product product = new Product();
        product.setDate(new Date());
        product.setStatus("Active");
        prods.add(product);
        invoice.setProducts(prods);
        invoiceRepository.save(invoice);
        product.setInvoice(invoice);
        //linked Product with the invoice_id before saving it
        productRepository.save(product);
    }
}
```